# Django REST framework - Serializing and Deserializing a list of primitive types

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, django-rest-framework

The task at hand is to use a Serializer to serialize a list of primitive types lets say integers or strings, and then to deserialize this list again. This should be really easy but somehow I cannot quite make it work. I managed to serialize a simple model and it looks like this:

```
{'title': u'Something', 'description': u'sldfj', 'price': Decimal('78.56'), 'numbers': [3, 2, 1]}
```

...so that do I have to do to reconstruct the numbers list? My Serializer looks like this:

```
class OfferSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    price = serializers.DecimalField()
    numbers = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance:
            for key, val in attrs.items():
                setattr(instance, key, val)
            return instance

        return Offer(**attrs)
```

With mongoengine one can simply say `ListField(IntField())` and everything is fine. Do I have to write my own ListSerializer?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need serialization then just using a regular `Field` will be fine.

If you need deserialization as well, then writing a custom field type is probably the best option, as rest framework does not yet have generic list or dict container fields.